# Floating Action Button library to use in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, floating-action-button

I need to use FAB (like compose button in gmail),

I searched the net and found lots of FAB library online, but the problem is they are all for Android Studio (aar files).

I also have problem updating AppCompat to its newer version so that I can use the Float Bar in it.

Isn't there any library (jar file) for FAB to use in Ecplise?

Comment: Well aside from the fact the eclipse is no longer supported, what is the problem you have with the new version that you cannot use it in eclipse

Answer (score 1):

You can use almost any library available for Android Studio and adapt for Eclipse.

This is a library on github which does not require any modification: [android-floating-button-eclipse](https://github.com/alopix/Android-FloatingActionButton-Eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

https://gist.github.com/Jogan/9def6110edf3247825c9  try this no need of any library or any additional jar files. works fine with eclipse.